# JBoss Switchyard annotations not resolving

Tags: web-services, soap, annotations, jboss7.x

I'm a noob to Switchyard. I've got everything set up (AS7 installed and running, accepting and responding SOAP messages, Eclipse with Switchyard and Maven plugins).

I created a new Switchyard project in Eclipse and copied over a few of the demo .java files from the AS7 distribution src folder.

For some reason however, despite Maven including all of the necessary Switchyard jar files, the @Service annotation is unable to be resolved. I fiddled with the build path, insuring that the resources were ordered properly, but that did me no good. I would have to assume that all of the Switchyard annotations are unresolvable right now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Maven simply wasn't including the right jar files due to the file structure that existed. Just ended up adding the needed jar files manually.